# limsup and liminf of sequence of intervals in $\mathbb R$ (2)

Tags: real-analysis, limsup-and-liminf

> Consider the sequence of intervals
>   $$ { I_n = \left( 2+\frac{(-1)^n}{n+1} , 10 +\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n+1} \right) }$$
>   Find $ \limsup I_n$, $\liminf I_n$, $\bigcup_{n=0}^{n=100} \bigcap_{n=0}^{n=100} I_n$, $\bigcap_{n=0}^{n=100} \bigcup_{n=0}^{n=100} I_n$.

For $\limsup I_n , \liminf I_n$ I tried to find the unions and the intersections finding first  the unions and the intersections of $ I_{2k}$ and $I_{2k+1}$

Any help?

Thank's in advance!

Comment: Where are you stuck? This seems a matter of merely applying the definitions... And the comments on your previous question still apply.

Comment: @Didier: For example how can I find $ \cap_{n=k}^{\infty} I_n $ and $\cup_{n=k}^{\infty} I_n$ ?

Comment: Surely you spotted that $I_k\approx(2,10)$ or $[2,10]$ or $(2,10]$ or $[2,10)$ when $k\to\infty$? Basically, the task is to determine which one is correct.

Comment: What does $\bigcap_{n=0}^{n=100} \bigcup_{n=0}^{n=100} I_n$ mean? You can't use the same index variable $n$ in both operators.