# Finding limsup and liminf for odd and even $A_n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, elementary-set-theory, limsup-and-liminf

I am trying to understand $\limsup$ and $\liminf$. I have this homework problem:
For each natural number $n$, let $A_n=[0,1]$ if $n$ is odd, and $A_n=[1,2]$ if $n$ is even. Find both $\limsup_{n\to\infty}A_n$ and $\liminf_{n\to\infty}A_n$.

Comment: By $[0,1]$ and $[1,2]$ are you referring to the closed intervals? i.e. you're trying to find the $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ of a sequence of sets?

Comment: You can have a look at similar previously asked questions, for example, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/144174/limsup-and-liminf-of-sequence-of-intervals-in-mathbb-r-2
and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/870615/limsup-of-intervals-infty-n-sin1-n

Comment: I am assuming so. This is a homework problem that appears as above.